# How can I test if the queries I am writing returns the correct result?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, sqlite

I am developing a Ruby on Rails application, and I have constructed some complicated queries.

Is there a way to test if the results that I have is correct?

Unit tests provide testing for each model, but how I can test if my results are correct?

Comment: From what class are you running said queries (a Controller, a Model, etc.)?

Comment: I run from controller, and I know the context of my database